# Why does MobileFirst throws GadgetAPIServlet Error Intermittently

Tags: iphone, mobilefirst-server

Below error is observed in MobileFirst log and app wont proceed. This issue is intermittent. Please advise.

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[GadgetAPIServlet]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: Invalid gadget request format: /WorkExecution/iphone/my_custom_auth_request_url. Unknown handler path: my_custom_auth_request_url [project TESTMOBILE]
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:632)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1301)
        at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:289)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:914)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:461)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:528)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:314)
        at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)

Comment: MFP 7.1 is out of support. That said, are you running in session dependent mode?

Comment: Hi Vivin...thanks for response...is it mfp.session.independent property in worklight.properties? Don't see this there as of now. Shall I explicitly add this and try ?

Comment: check the logs for "mfp.session.independent" and see if this is true or false. And when this issue is seen, if the client retries submitting credentials, does it work?

Comment: Hi...yes...on retry it works.... sometime fails on retry also......this issue is intermittent...

Comment: Hi...nothing like "mfp.session.independent" in logs...seems by default MF runs in this mode........any work around you can suggest?